# AngularJS: inject service into directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, d3.js

I've been trying to integrate D3.js with Angular, and am following this tutorial:
http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html

The tutorial creates a d3 module which contains `d3Service`, and that gets injected into a directive. My app has a slightly different structure, but whenever I try to inject the d3 service, it shows up as `undefined` in my directive `link` function. I can inject the d3 service into my controller without issue. Here's what I'm doing:

`app.js`:

```
var sentimentApp = angular.module('sentimentApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngSanitize',
  'sentimentAppServices',
  'sentimentAppDirectives',
  'sentimentAppControllers'
]);
```

Within `services.js`, I have several services, one of which is d3:

```
var sentimentAppServices = angular.module('sentimentAppServices', ['ngResource'])
// other services
.factory('d3', [function(){
  var d3;
  d3 = // d3 library code here
  return d3; 
}]);
```

Now in `directives.js`:

```
var sentimentAppDirectives = angular.module('sentimentAppDirectives', ['sentimentAppServices']);

sentimentAppDirectives.directive('lsPieChart', ['d3', function($compile, d3){
   return {
     // scope & template
     link: function($scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
       console.log(d3); // undefined
     }
   }
```

Any tips? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that your hinted dependencies don't match up to what you're actually passing in:

```
['$compile, d3', function($compile, d3
```

So, what you were doing is passing the `d3` service as the variable `$compile` and not passing anything as the variable `d3`.

It might help you to understand what this is for. In non-minified code, you could take out that array wrapper altogether, like this:

```
app.directive('directiveName', function($compile, d3) {
  // ....
});
```

The point of passing the names as a string is because strings won't be affected by minification. This means that angular will know how to inject the right dependencies in a case like this:

```
 ['$compile, d3', function(a, b
```

`a` will be set to the `$compile` service and `b` to your `d3` service.

Comment: Note that you don't need this always if you use ngmin utilitiy (in case of doing it before minification) as it is to be done automatically. This can simplify maintenance as you can accidentally run into the similar problem like described in the subject.