# Using service inside directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am learning how to create custom directives.

My **service** looks like that:

```
myApp.service('myService',function(){
    this.myFunction=function(myParam){
        // do something
    }
});
```

Here is my **directive**:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective',function(myService){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          param: '=myParam',
        },
        template: '<button ng-click="myService.myFunction(param)">Do action</button>',
    }
});
```

In HTML, when I use `<my-directive my-param="something"></my-directive>` it properly renders as a button. However when I click it, `myService.myFunction`, doesn't get executed.

I suppose I am doing something wrong. Can someone give me a direction?
I guess this has something to do with the directive's scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service wont be available directly inside the template. You'll have to use a function attached to the directive's `scope` and call the service function from within this function.

```
myApp.directive('myDirective',function(myService){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          param: '=myParam',
        },
        template: '<button ng-click="callService(param)">Do action</button>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.callService = function() {
                myService.myFunction();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This obviously works, but especially when you write tests this directive is quite hard to test. When you write all logic in your controller it becomes easier to maintain, and easier to test. So I always recommend to use a controller for your logic instead of the link-function.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because in your example a directive doesn't actually know what is `myService`. You have to explicitly inject it e.g.:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', ['myService', function(myService){ ... }]);
```

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569168/injecting-service-to-directive) or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211695/angularjs-inject-service-into-directive).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a controller to do all DOM-modifications.
See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/HbfD1EzS0av5BG6NgtIv?p=preview

```
.directive('myFirstDirective', [function() {
  return {
    'restrict': 'E',
    'controller': 'MyFirstController',
    'controllerAs': 'myFirstCtrl',
    'template': '<h1>First directive</h1><input type="text" ng-model="myFirstCtrl.value">'
  };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can inject the service in the controller and then call that function inside your template:

Inject `myService` into controller:

```
myApp.controller("ctrl", function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.doService = function(myParam) {
        return myService.myFunction(myParam);
    };
});
```

Call `doService` method of the controller inside your template:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          param: '=myParam',
        },
        template: '<button ng-click="doService(param)">Do action</button>',
    }
});
```

Comment: -1. With this strategy, you end up with a very tightly coupled controller/directive pair. It's virtually impossible to use that directive anywhere else, unless by defining exactly the same functions names, with the same purpose. Directives are meant to be easy to reuse.